# Adding headervalue to all requests towards server

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there a way to adding a header value to all requests against the sever. Or an other efficient way of handling this.

My ideas so far by order of plasuibility;

1. Somehow extending htmlhelper to adding a header tag for all html.actionlink ajax.form etc... Don't know if this is possible
2. Some kind of server overide where all requewsts have to have a certain header param.
3. ???

Is this even plausible to achive without sending this as an extra param to every action?

Some background i want to send some form of SessionID with every request so i know no session collide between browser tabs. My first idea is to have it as a header value in *all* requests and add some filter to the base controller checking this ID against the ID  saved in the session.

Comment: Why not set a session? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Comment: If i have a new user signing in in different tab. I close previus session and clear the data . (all good so far) . However if i have some from up in the previous tab. I can post data from old tab to this new tab.  Not desierd. So i want to have previous Sesson id ( in this post ) so i can redirect to some geric error page.